# Clarification for implication

Tags: logic

I am confused with the definition of implication:

> Does $1$ belong to the set $\{n\in \Bbb N : \text {if } n\ne 1 \text { then } n-1\in\Bbb N\}$?
>
> Does $\pi$ belong to the set $\{n : \text {if } n\in \Bbb N \text { and }n\ne 1 \text { then } n-1\in\Bbb N\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a bit of a mind-bender. We can write the predicates as $$ \phi_1(n) =\left( n\ne 1\Rightarrow n-1 \in \mathbb N\right)\\\phi_2(n) = ([n\in \mathbb N \wedge n\ne 1] \Rightarrow n-1\in \mathbb N) $$ and remember that an implication is false only if the LHS is true and the RHS is false.

So is $1$ an integer satisfying $\phi_1?$ Well note that the premise (LHS) of the conditional is false, so the conditional is true. Thus $1$ is an element of the set.

For the second I guess we're to assume the universe quantified over contains $\pi$ (since the $n$ before the colon is unrestricted it's not really specified). Again you should see that the premise is false, and thus the conditional is true, so $\pi$ is a member of the set. (Assuming, again, that it's in the universe being quantified over. If it isn't then of course it can't be in the set.)

Answer (score 1):

You have that $1 \in \mathbb{N}$ and complies the condition that if $n \neq 1, n-1 \in \mathbb{N}$ because $n=1$. So 1 belongs to the set.

The second one you have to specify at the beggining if n is real, complex, rational, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This question points out some of the limitations of set-builder notation. Equivalent to your first set is set $S$ such that

$$\forall n:[n\in S \iff n\in N \land [n\ne 1 \implies n-1 \in N]]$$

Since $A \implies B \equiv  \neg A \lor B$, we also have

$$\forall n:[n\in S \iff n\in N \land [n = 1 \lor n-1 \in N]]$$

If we specify $n=1$, then the answer should be apparent with very little "mind bending."

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

the first set is exactly
$$\mathbb N-\{0\}=\{1,2,3,....\}. $$

it does not contain $0$ because $0-1\notin \mathbb N $.